# SBS 2011 Error MSSQL$SBSMONITORING size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm running a SBS 2011 Server. I'm getting a series of critical application errors starting with this one.

> > CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database.

This error appears every minute or so with some cascading errors like

> > Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.EventLog'.'PK_EventLog' in database 'SBSMonitoring' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

I've got plenty of disk space, but this appears to be a problem with SQL file size limits. How do I clean this up? Thanks!

Comment: From the message it seems that your licence is for 10GB per database. It has nothing to do with disk space

Comment: I agree. I'm just not sure what to do to make this database smaller.

Comment: perhaps you could create another database and transfer there all "historic" records?

Answer (score 0):

The first thought after reading "10240 MB per database" was "SQL Server Express?". Are you sure you're not using the Express version of SQL Server? If you are, that's the source of the problem and that is the main downside to using the free software.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508696(v=ws.11).aspx states that standard edition of sbs 2011 comes with sql server express. Which version of SBS are you using (standard or premium)?

Comment: I've never installed SQL Server Express. I'm assuming SBSMONITORING database is part of SBS 2011.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using premium SBS2011. From SBS programs it lists SQL Server 2008 R2 in the programs. There is no mention of express. Regardless, It seems that I need to reduce the database size. Just not sure how to do it. I've been using this server for six  years and guess the data is just piling up.